# Alternative to storing form info in browser session

Tags: php, mysql

I want visitors to my site to fill out a job post before they sign up for an account. Once the job post info is filled in and user signs up, the job will not actually be posted till the user confirms his email address. My issue is that if the user closes his browser and confirms his account later, the job post is gone because I'm saving it in the browser session. Is there a better way to address this problem?

Comment: Erm... storing it in the long-living cookie (that is deleted when user deletes their post)? Actually I'd store it into DB (but used 'activated = 1' in the query fetching it), but it looks like for some reason that's not suitable for you.

Comment: Store it in the job table (assuming you have one) with a new column (active) set to 0, when the user validates their email you can set the active column to 1 and the job will be shown.. just an idea

Comment: I can't store the job in the database because at that point there's no user ID to link it to.  What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Store the information in a database.

You're going to have to do that eventually anyway for other people to view it.

You can't rely on a session as they expire.

**In reponse to comment:**

If you're not storing the email address to begin with before sending the email out, then you're not really doing email verification. I would store the email address in a user table with a verified flag of 0. Then when the user verifies you can set it to 1. Then you know that anything linked with this user can be displayed.

Comment: I can't store the job in the database because at that point there's no user ID to link it to.  What can I do?